# How to deal with special characters in C?

Tags: c, string, locale, setlocale

I'm trying to read (with fgets) and write (with printf) strings with latin special characters (such as ç, á, è, etc).

I've tried to use the setlocale funcion in several different ways, without any positive result. Sometimes the string that I read is written in a good as I want, but in this case, the constant strings (hardcoded in the program) are written with strange characters, and vice-versa.

For example, I've tried these options:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Portuguese")
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Portuguese_Brazil.1252")
```

I'm wondering if the encoding of my file code has something to do with this problem.

How can I deadl with this issue?

Comment: Tip: Try writing first.  Your code's _locale_ is important and the terminal's configuration is important too.  Try `puts("such as ç, á, è, etc\n");` and again after `setlocale(something)` and report results.

Comment: OS makes a huge difference too. The Windows Console, in particular, needs some special care to work right with Unicode. Best solution: use ICU. The C API for ICU works swimmingly on every OS, and every major OS comes with it pre-installed, and it works -- even on Windows.